# foreach loop only on certain characters from a string

Tags: c#

I'm trying to pull the values inside I'm checking for outside a function as a public List.

from this

```
charString.Where(n => n == ';' || n == '|' || n == '\t' || n == ':' || n == ','))
```

to this

```
public List<char> PossibleDelimiters = new List<char> { ';', '|' ,'\t' , ':', ',' };
```

Then check against inside the function

```
foreach (char currentChar in charString.Where(n => n == ';' || n == '|' || n == '\t' || n == ':' || n == ',')) 
{
    int foundCharOccreence = 0;
    foreach (char charToBeMatch in charString.Where(n => n == ';' || n == '|' || n == '\t' || n == ':' || n == ',')) 
    {
        if (currentChar == charToBeMatch)
            foundCharOccreence++;
    }
    if (mostOccurrence < foundCharOccreence) 
    {
        mostOccurrence = foundCharOccreence;
        mostOccurringChar = currentChar;
    }
}
```

I tried to attempt the following:

```
foreach (char currentChar in charString.Where(PossibleDelimiters.Contains()) 
{
```

But I'm sure what to check against. I want to execute the `foreach` loop only the characters in the list.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Isn't it this you are trying to get to?

```
foreach (char currentChar in charString.Where(n => PossibleDelimiters.Contains(n)))
```

Comment: Well that was simple! I was just missing the syntax. Thanks for the help!

Comment: That's what I figured. Glad that helped.

Answer (score 1):

```
 foreach (char currentChar in charString.Where(c => PossibleDelimiters.Contains(c )) {
//do something to matching char
}
```

Comment: Ah just beaten to it!